# image not loaded after <img..> appended with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html

My website contains the following code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails1">
  <li>
   <img src="~/Images/man1.jpg" alt="n/a"/>
   </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="See More" onclick="OnSeeMore()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSeeMore() {
  $('.thumbnails1').prepend('<li><img src="~/Images/man1.jpg" alt="n/a"/></li>');
}
</script>
```

The original image appears well, but when i click "See More" button, I can see the list item is dynamically added, but the image shows the "alt" text n/a instead of the "man1.jpg" image. so what am I doing wrong?
I basically try to copy google's image search behavior, by showing only some of the images in the DB and then show more upon request.

Comment: Are any network requests made and does it try to load the right image?

Comment: are you prepending the images or appending the images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~/Images/man1.jpg` is a server-side relative path. If you are adding the node on the client side, you need to use `/Images/man1.jpg` assuming the Images folder is in the root folder for your site.

Comment: Thanks ! (to all).
I just removed the ~ (a relative path on .Net indeed) and also I modified the src to point to my server RESTful service which returns an image data by its name.

Answer (score 5):

The relative path:

```
<img src="~/Images/man1.jpg"
```

Should be "resolved" on the server, if you add it on the client as is, the path is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your URL include a `~`? It should not use some linux specifc path since that is not a URL. It should be the path to get to it from the webserver, not the file system.

```
<!-- Relative -->
<img src="./Images/man1.jpg" alt="n/a"/>

<!-- Absolute -->
<img src="/Path/to/my/directory/Images/man1.jpg" alt="n/a"/>
```

Comment: It's a relative path in .Net

Comment: @gdoron: Why would you use something like that instead of just using `Images/man1.jpg`

Comment: It's called relative path, one moment I'll give you a link.

Comment: @gdoron A relative path is usually `./Images/man1.jpg` why the alternative syntax?

Comment: Here, I found [a learning resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne)

Comment: It means relative to the application root. And so means that paths work regardless of whether the application is deployed to a site root or some sub application within a site. Using site-root relative paths such as your `/Path/` example doesn't work if you are developing against `http://localhost/somesite` but then deploy to  `http://www.somesite.com`

Comment: @gdoron I see, it's very specific to .net and it has to be used on the server side, it's not a real relative URL, it's .net's hack

Comment: @JuanMendes. Correct! I don't like it either too much, so as for real relative paths which cause many troubles too many times...